# How to add a caption to tabulary?

Tags: tables, captions, tabulary

I'm having problem to add the caption to a table when I use tabulary. 
Here's my code but I don't understand where I make the mistake...

```
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LLLL}
\caption{Summary of the technological likeness in the aeronautical industry for three AM's processes. Adapted from \cite{hopkinson2006rapid}}
\label{tab:AM_tech_likeness}
\hline
 & SL   & SLS   & FDM        \\
\hline
Materials:          \\

Use acceptable production grade materials     & Current acceptance is slow  & Most versatile, can process both plastics and metals & Advantage of being able to use commercial grade plastics (ABS, PS, PC)  \\

Processing \say{exotic} materials & \say{Exotic} materials are a possibility, but no metals. & Currently metals such A6, Inconel and aluminium, while in future titanium and others. & \say{Exotic} materials an issue. \\ 
\hline
\end{tabulary}
```

Comment: as for tabular, `\caption` goes before the tabulary it is part of the surrounding `table` environment.

Answer (score 4):

As for `tabular`, `\caption` goes before the `tabulary`. It is part of the surrounding `table` environment.